# Capturar palavras com acento com Scanner

Tags: java

Estou usando um Scanner, no Java, para captura de Palavras/Frases; porém quando eu digito uma palavra que contém acentou ou 'ç', a letra se transforma em um 'quadrado'!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao instanciar seu `Scanner` você pode informar o [`charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)) que deseja utilizar. Então, considere usar algo como isto:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
```

A linha acima é um exemplo, você deve informar o `charset` que necessita tais como os presentes [aqui](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

Comment: Bem, o código que você me passou não funcionou, porém, partindo deste eu troquei o "UTF-8" por "latin1" aí sim funcionou. Mesmo assim Obrigado!

Comment: Sim @NickolasCarlos, como dito você pode informar o `charset`. Este foi um exemplo, você deve mesmo informar o que é necessário no seu ambiente =). Vou editar para melhor explicar isto, obrigado.